# JUnit Test Android with above 80 % Code Coverage

Tags: unit-testing

I have to write junit test for all the class used in the project in android with above 80 % code coverage

Comment: What's your exact question? It could help to split up your question into more than one sentence ;)

Comment: have to write unit test for  this method with code coverage report   public void setToolbar(String toolbartitle, int view) {
        tvToolbarTitle.setText(toolbartitle);
        ivBackButton.setVisibility(view);
    }

Comment: Please add all explanation to your question by editing it